# Should the SSL and TLS tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a [three questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tls) regarding TLS, and 100+ regarding SSL.  Considering that SSL and TLS are the same thing, perhaps we should edit the wiki and have an alias for them.

On a related note should we permit version-specific tagging (ie TLS1.1)?

Answer (score 4):

There looks to be some agreement on this. From the [Tag Synonyms](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest) page, Hendrik also suggested this back on Sept. 17. While I do not have enough rep in those tags to vote on it, I do agree.

Answer (score 2):

OK I approved this synonym and merged it.