# What's your angle on [Angular]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The name "Angular" is used to refer to Angular 2.0 and upwards, while the name "AngularJS" refers to the old 1.x version.

We have had [angularjs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) for some time, it has 32 questions. Recently, a separate [angular](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular) was created, and now has two questions. In practice, there are a lot of questions tagged with [angularjs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) that are actually about [angular](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular).

How do we deal with this? I see two possibilities:

1. Try to separate the tags, retagging old and new questions so they use the correct tag. I think a lot of new questions will not use the correct tag, and it will be hard to keep the tags properly separated. This seems like a lot of work, with little reward.
2. Make [angularjs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) a synonym of [angular](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular). Less work, no incorrectly tagged questions. But off course, a little loss of specificity.

I would support #2. What do you think?

Comment: There seems to be precdent for #2. [tag:ssl] was made a synonym of [tag:tls] by none other than Jeff Atwood: https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/582/should-the-ssl-and-tls-tags-be-merged

Comment: Done, it's pretty straightforward - IMO it is an obvious fix.

Comment: @AviD You made [tag:angular] a synonym of [tag:angularjs]. Could we have it the other way around, so the main tag is the name currently in use? Not a big deal either way, but if its simple to fix.

Comment: the main tag is `angularjs`, which had substantially more questions than `angular`. I also think it makes more sense, to be more explicit with the `js` framework bit. Honestly I think `angular-js` would have been even better, but at that point I lazied out ;-)

Comment: @AviD The framework is no longer called angularjs, just angular. But we are bikeshedding this already! :-) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I support Nr. 2.

I think that questions about AngularJS 1.x can just differentiate themselves by mentioning that it's specifically about the obsolete version 1.x.